# Wi-Fi - Intermittent "Connected, no internet" driving me crazy! What could be causing it?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, wireless-router

The router (TP-Link TL-WR840N) is connected to a switch, which is connected to the ISP provided (wifi) router.

Every couple of days, the internet will disconnect  and say ["Connected, no internet"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W67c2.png). Then, after a while (a couple of hours) it will come back by itself.

There are two TP-Link TL-WR840Ns connected to the ISP router and this happens to both of them simultaneously.

Restarting them makes no difference.

I've tried taking the switch out of the equation and connecting them directly to the ISP provided router, but I get no internet connection that way. I've tried that even when the internet is working fine...if I disconnect the cable from the switch and connect it to the ISP router, no internet. Remove it from the ISP router and connect it back to the switch, internet works. I'd love to know why that is. And yes I'm connecting the cables at the right ports.

When there is no internet at the two routers, the ISP router is working fine and I'm able to connect to the internet through it.

I've tried restarting both the switch and the ISP router but that also makes no difference.

Logging in to the web interface of the router, I see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZlQf.png) and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTgyl.png).

Any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: The images clearly show that the routers have lost the WAN port IP address. That will prevent any connectivity through the WAN port. You should look at the ISP router to find out why that's not working. If the problem's just the DHCP service, giving your routers WAN interfaces static IPs in correct range (including appropriate gateway and DNS server addresses) should resolve it.

Comment: "If the problem's just the DHCP service, giving your routers WAN interfaces static IPs in correct range (including appropriate gateway and DNS server addresses) should resolve it." Could you elaborate on this please? I didn't quite get it. How do I go about doing that?

Comment: The images truly show no internet connection. The problem is in the ISP router, so better call their Support. Which router is also the DHCP server? (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Answer (score 0):

Configure the ISP router like this:

1. Reserve a IP address (example: 192.168.1.2) to your routers MAC address (88-79-7E-F7-1C-BC) from the LAN IP range. Note what IP address the ISP router have on the LAN (example: 192.168.1.1)

Configure your TP-link routers like this:

1. Change your TP-link routers WAN configuration to:

   - WAN IP : 192.168.1.1
   - WAN subnet: 255.255.255.0
   - WAN DNS: : 192.168.1.1
2. Change your TP-link routers LAN configuration if it uses the 192.168.1.0/24 network to some other network (example: 192.168.2.0/24).

   - LAN IP : 192.168.2.1
   - LAN subnet: 255.255.255.0
   - DNS: : 192.168.1.1

**Note!** The IP addresses used above is just EXAMPLES, please adjust them to IP addresses used in you network.

Comment: Is #1 to be done on the TP-Link router or the ISP router? Could you expound on how exactly to go about doing that. "reserve"? What are the steps? Thsbs!

Comment: @JJrussel I have no idea what type of ISP router the OP have since that info isnt in the question! Normally a reservation is done under LAN/DHCP menues. As for #1, I have edited the answer so its clearer.